# Force, opposite direction

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, work

> Force of constant intensity of 25.5 N acts on the block as shown in the figure, with the block moving 7.2 m to the right. Determine the work done by the force. Friction can be ignored.

W= F × s × cos 30°
W= 159 J
I did it like this, but I doubt it's true because the force is in the opposite direction to the block

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$W=\vec{F}\cdot\vec{s}\implies W=|\vec{F}||\vec{s}|cos(\theta)$, where $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec{F}$ and $\vec{s}$. In this case, $\theta=210°$. You already know $|\vec{F}|$ and $|\vec{s}|$, so substitute in the values and you’ll have your answer. It’s worth noticing that $cos(180+x)=-cos(x)$, where $0°\leq x\leq180°$.

Comment: W = 25.5 × 7.2 × cos 210 ° W = -159 J Can you explain to me a little more why we take an angle of 210 °? Thank you

Comment: Well, it’s like you said. The force is opposite to the displacement. Imagine an arrow pointing in the direction of the force, and another arrow pointing in the direction of the displacement. Without changing the direction of the arrows, join them end to end (join the ends without the arrow tip). Find the angle between them. This is the angle between the force and the displacement. Because of how work is defined, this is the angle we need to consider. The physical intuition behind the dot product is not something I can explain in a comment, though.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry for the annoyance, just one more thing Is e.g. error if we take an angle of 150 ° by subtracting 30 ° of 180 °. The cosine of 150 ° is the same as the cosine of 210 °

Comment: Well, you can since $cos(180-x)=cos(180+x)$, but I like to use the geometric visualisation of arrows and take the angle between the arrows. Your way is not a recommended way to think about the angles between vectors, though, as $sin(180-x)$ is not, in general, equal to $sin(180+x)$. Not just the sine function, many other trig functions don’t have the same property.

Comment: Thank you a lot Heisenberg 

Comment: Glad to help, man.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the mass is moving to the right on a horizontal friction-less surface, then the sum of the vertical forces is zero, and the horizontal component of the applied force [F cos(30)] is doing negative work which is causing a decrease in the kinetic energy of the mass.